# Как очистить errorprovider через заданный timeout?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть 10 контролов, есть один `errorprovider`. Если в контроле нет текста, появляется сообщение типа

```
 errorProvider1.SetError(extensionNumBox, "Поле «Добавочный номер» обязательно для заполнения");
```

Все хорошо, однако значок ошибки остается, а мне хотелось бы чтобы он секунд 5 помигал, потом оповещение исчезло. 
Если я делаю так

```
 errorProvider1.SetError(extensionNumBox, "");
```

То у меня не успевает отображаться сама ошибка.

Comment: А какой графический фреймворк вы используете?

Comment: в смысле фреймворк?

Comment: Ну, в языке C# понятия errorprovider нету. Раз вы говорите о контролах и тексте, следовательно, вы пользуетесь каким-то графическим фреймворком, к которому, судя по всему, и относится понятие errorprovider. Поскольку вы не указали в метках ваш фреймворк, я переспросил.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider

Comment: Используйте таймер или `await Task.Delay()`. Нажали на кнопку, заполнили `ErrorProvider`, запустили таймер/подождали, очистили `ErrorProvider` для всех контролов.

Comment: можно пример плз?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте таймер или `await Task.Delay()`:

1. Заполнили `ErrorProvider`.
2. Запустили таймер/подождали.
3. Очистили `ErrorProvider` для всех контролов (если будете использовать таймер, не забудьте использовать `Invoke`, поскольку колбэк таймера вызывается не в UI потоке).

Пример с использованием `Task.Delay()`:

```
private async void btnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Validate();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    ClearValidation();
}

private void Validate()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(extensionNumBox.Text))
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(
            extensionNumBox,
            "Поле «Добавочный номер» обязательно для заполнения");
    }

    // другие проверки
}

private void ClearValidation()
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(extensionNumBox, string.Empty);

    // очищаем другие контролы
}
```